# Salesforce Lightning Design System : Can we create side bar menu similar to lightning experience using LDS?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Salesforce Lightning Design System : Can we create side bar menu similar to lightning experience using LDS?

Here is the attached sample:
[image]